# Tamper proof way to verify a 'confirm' email link with preventive measures for tampering?

Tags: java, activation

Story for context:
I have an ePetition type service running on my site which I email people a link where they can 'agree' to the petition. This link will only contain the 'petitionID' and 'username' of the person who sent it.

This information isn't particularly sensitive but I still require it to be tamper-proof because I want them to be able to accept without signing in or storing values in the database.

I thought of using Java's String.hashCode() function.

Maybe having the url as: username, petitionId and then a hash

```
www.website.com/accept.jsp?user='username'&id='petid'&token='1039678106'
```

The token could be made up of username + id(from the link) + datePetitionStarted(like the salt not exposed in the url) like:

```
String test = "mike.Who@petitionwebsite.com+1524+09/02/2016";
        System.out.println(test.hashCode());
```

This would give me a hash of '1039678106' which means server side, I can take the ID parameter, the username of the person and use the datePetitionStarted, get the hashcode and compare them.

Do you think this is a valid way of preventing tampering?

I'm really after a token-type method of accepting petitions so if anyone has any other ideas that would be awesome.

thanks,

Mike

Comment: You'll need some secret. Probably best to use HMAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did (which is practically tamper-proof). I don't use java script as users can disable it anyway. I simply create a UUID,  (which is stored in a database next to user details) and then create a link sent in an email during the registration process.

```
http://my_domain_name/Activate?key=6faeecf5-9ab3-46f4-9785-321a5bbe2ace
```

When the user clicks on the link above, the server side code checks that this key actually exists in the database, in which case it activates the user account.

Comment: This is a great solution, storing a hash in the database will also be ideal but unfortunately I don't want the user to have to log in or use a database in general.

Comment: That's why they can best have an expire time much less than the time needed to successfully bruteforce one. E.g. one hour. Then just tell client "Sorry, key expired, click to regenerate one, blah blah".

Comment: @Satya Even if you guessed the UUID, you'd still have to guess the user credentials in order to successfully log in (the UUID alone is not enough).

Comment: @dsp_user I didn't say that by using only UUID some one can login to others account. I just said that its easily guessable.

Comment: Ok, I thought you meant that. :)

Comment: I decided to use a database after all, and the UUID + login details were the best way to verify the hash. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the String.hashcode() may return the same value for the same string across instances, this is not guaranteed.

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. **This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.**

API docs for [Object.hashcode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

As such, if you were to down down this route you should use your own hash.